# How to load a static file in django2.0

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am having difficulty loading static files in django2.0 (coming from django1.4). Here is what I have so far:

```
# urls.py
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)

# settings.py
TEMPLATES = [
            ...
            'builtins': [
              'django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.staticfiles',
             ],
]
SITE_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = ''
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
  os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, "static"),    
]
```

And I have one image located at:

```
[my_project_root]/static/img/image.png
```

Now if I go directly to the url, I get a 404:

```
http://localhost:8000/static/img/image.png
```

Additionally, if I do it "through the template", I also get a 404:

```
{% load static %}
<img src="{% static 'img/image.png' %}" alt="My image">
```

What do I need to add here to serve the static files?

Comment: what is the value of `SITE_ROOT`? are you sure the file is located at `project_root/static/img`?

Comment: @Lemayzeur -- it should be fine: `SITE_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))`. It's working for my `templates` and other items that use it currently.

Comment: are you using builtin Django webserver ?

Comment: @PankajSharma yes.

Comment: are you sure the file is located at `project_root/static/img`?

Comment: in django version nowadays the variable name is `BASE_DIR` and it should be `BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))` rather than `SITE_ROOT=os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))`

Comment: in django version nowadays the variable name is `BASE_DIR` and it should be `BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))` rather than `SITE_ROOT=os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))`

Comment: @Lemayzeur right, I've moved my settings into the top-level directory, so I'm not traversing back two directories, but yes the above is the 'standard' way as recommended by django docs, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a tricky setting. I needed to change the `STATIC_ROOT` to:

```
STATIC_ROOT = 'static/'
```

Otherwise, with `STATIC_ROOT` = '', it would look for the img file in `[project_root]/img/image.png`.